# How to search python function definitions across all installed packages in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I want to search for a function name across all installed packages and also in the packages defined by python.autoComplete.extraPaths vscode setting.

Vscode search panel searches only in the current workspace. Whereas in pycharm IDE ctrl + click on a word is able to search across all packages.

Is there a way to search for function definition across all installed packages using vscode IDE?

Comment: Opened  a discussion here https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/discussions/3187